# Left Column Sidebar Not Showing Up on Shop Pages

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, theme

I have a left column static block that shows an image for my CMS pages. Why does this image not show on the Shop left column sidebar as well? When I inspect each element, both have the same div's.

I've included images.

[image: Sidebar showing up]

[image: Sidebar Missing]

Comment: Post the code you have tried to shoe the static block in all page.

Comment: I just went to CMS > Widgets > [widget name] > and it is set as Display On All pages On Left Column in conjunction with my CMS Static Block with the images.

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons why the widget would not show there.

1) make sure that the design package/theme is the one that you use.

2) make sure that the left structural block is included in your page and it is not removed by your theme.

3) make sure that your content is not overwritten (most likely xml in local.xml).

A tool that might help you: system -> configurat -> developer. chose website view and set template files to yes. Refresh and you will see in red lines what exactly is called there.